# flexible data in online application

Tags: php, mysql, database, project, data-storage

I am looking for some insights in how to best store and process data in my project. I already have a running set-up of my online-application but am looking for ways to make the data easier to handle and manipulate. I am a teacher and I store information about my students in this application. I make it accessible to them, so they can see their progress, and show some simple calculations based on that data. I have identified a couple of issues and would appreciate tips or help to improve my application.

**1) Data-source:**
I have 2 sources of data:

- I store the data into a google-spreadsheet which is sent into a mysql-database (on demand). Although I like the setup that I have the data in 2 different locations/systems I occasionally have the problem that if I have to change something in the database I have to change it in the spreadsheet as well. The Spreadsheet was kind of a necessity so far as I did not have internet access during classes (most of the time).
- I created an online quiz for my students. It directly stores the results into a mysql database.

**2) Data storage:**
I use an MySQL-Database as datastorage for the online applications. As I do not want to make hundreds of queries for each task I store each of my classes into a multidimensional array and use it for calculations. (which sounds like extremely bad coding to me but it worked so I did not change it...)
I would like to have a simple way to query data in a flexible way. I would like to compare class performances, specific students from different classes, create class averages, year averages, male/female statistics, graphs etc.

**3) Offline:**
I would like to maybe have the opportunity to have an offline accessible version of this application in the future. It would not have to have full functionality but at least to show and browse data without the option to add new entries.

I am willing to change the set-up of this application in order to get access to more flexible data-manipulation/calculation. So if you have any tips or guidance I would really appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Comment: maybe to change from mysql database to linked data and rdf for flexibility?

Comment: Thank you! But isn't linked data stored locally? Or am I confusing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. *Data-source*: pick one or the other. Either go all sql or all spreadsheet but don't do both. Keeping the data consistent is already an issue and you'll make yourself crazy trying to maintain this. Google docs has a nice API for accessing spreadsheet data if you want to build something larger around this. MySQL is ... well... everywhere.
2. "I don't want to make hundreds of queries" - but you want to store and process data? All the metrics you mention are pretty straight-forward. You could go either DB or SS with this. You'd define the queries early on and be done with it.
3. Offline? Are you wanting to market this somehow? Why would it be offline? It's easy to define a 'read-only' access path to either the SS or DB.

I think you need to narrow this down quite a bit. It won't limit you overmuch and it will make this much easier to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the nice suggestions! I wanted to add some offline support because we do not have wi-fi at our school and everything is still done through cable-access. So sitting down with a student and talking about his progress would need at least some basic offline support.

Comment: Sounds like going with a google spreadsheet and putting your formulas in there is a reasonable place to start. There's probably a way to tie some forms in with that and reporting as well.